# How to turn on revealing of the problem when you point at this underscore in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my case it doesn't reveal the problem, but steal underlines it. I need to understand what's wrong, but I can't. No matter what the problem is, it is underlined, but I can't check it. Big mistakes are revealed in Problems, but other, the smaller ones...

I tried to ask my friends and teachers, but they have no idea of it.

Comment: You mean you don't get that info on mouse hover?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.